Date is incorrect in wifi : system clock synchronization is not active
I have compiled a read-only rootfs image with yocto for my raspberrypi4. I have noticed that my date is incorrect uniquely in wifi.
Indeed when I type the command timedatectl status I have the following:
System clock synchronized: no

I do not understand why this happen in wifi. In ethernet everything is fine, meaning date is correct and there is System clock synchronization when I type my timedatectl command.
I checked the following:

My NTP service is active
I do have the directory /var/lib/systemd/timesync/ (with clock inside)
I tried to activate system clock synchronization manually with timedatectl set-ntp true
Systemd service related to timesync did not failed (systemd-timesyncd)

I also tried to enable some debugs:
root@AFP:~# SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd 
Bus bus-api-timesync: changing state UNSET → OPENING
sd-bus: starting bus bus-api-timesync by connecting to /run/dbus/system_bus_socket...
Bus bus-api-timesync: changing state OPENING → AUTHENTICATING
Registering bus object implementation for path=/org/freedesktop/LogControl1 iface=org.freedesktop.LogControl1
Added new system server time1.google.com.
Added new fallback server time1.google.com.
Added new fallback server time2.google.com.
Added new fallback server time3.google.com.
Added new fallback server time4.google.com.
systemd-timesyncd running as pid 1255
Bus bus-api-timesync: changing state AUTHENTICATING → HELLO
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RequestName cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=su error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.19 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Bus bus-api-timesync: changing state HELLO → RUNNING
Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus.Local destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/DBus/Local interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Local member=Connected cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.19 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.19 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.19 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4 reply_cookie=2 signature=u error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Successfully acquired requested service name.

As you can see there is no server selection and request sending.
The ntp server can also be passed through networkd or NetworkManager via what is retrieved in dhcp. In this case how to activate time synchronization with NetworkManager.
At this point any help would be appreciated.
Note that my /etc/ and /var/lib directories are overlays.

I just removed networkd. Only one Network Manager is enough or there will be conflicts.
